# Will SyncFramework work without local tracking tables?

Tags: azure, microsoft-sync-framework, azure-data-sync

I'm wanting to know if syncframework will work without using local tracking tables. Azure tracking tables are ok and we're just uploading to Azure.

Reason is some of our clients db's aren't owned by us so we can't really be adding tables / increasing their size.

thanks,

Comment: Also,
will Azure DataSync work with older OS's - server 2003 or xp for example?

thanks

Comment: what do you expect the sync framework to do? you want it to (efficiently) keep track of what has changed?

Comment: Hi,yes I was unsure whether you needed a tracking table at the local level if I'm not syncing Azure to Local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tracking table is for recording what has changed. in your case, you actually needed it on local. Sync Fx will still provision the tracking tables in Azure though, useless if your Azure is never the source during sync.

minimum OS requirement for Azure Data Sync Agent is Vista or above.

you can get away without tracking tables using or writing a custom provider using the older offline provider model. however, you'd still need  tombstone tables to record the deletes.

Comment: Thanks June T, could you point me in the direction of more info on writing custom providers? However if we'd still need to add tables (tombstones) to the local then this probably wouldn't be good for us but I'd at the very least like to rule it out.

Comment: I was thinking maybe having a separate db on the local that regularly (every 5 mins) just copies the tables from the other db (that we can't add tables to) then using the syncframework on that - what's your thoughts? would copying tables frequently affect the performance of the main db?